# How to run Mojolicious app from command line with params?

Tags: perl, command-line, parameters, mojolicious

I have a Mojolicious application. It runs under Starman very well, but I want to run it from `command line` with parameters.

Command

`./myapp get /`

works as well, but

`./myapp get /?param=val`

does not work as there is not any parameter.

Can you help me?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my machine (Linux). Would you by any chance happen to be using Windows?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what are the errors? Is is a shell escaping error on the command line - that is do you need `./myapp get "/?param=val"` ... or is the application itself giving you errors?

Answer (score 2):

This is works.

```
# Automatically enables "strict", "warnings", "utf8" and Perl 5.10 features
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Route with placeholder
get '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $param = $self->param('param') // 'qwerty';

  $self->render(text => "Hello from $param.");
};

# Start the Mojolicious command system
app->start;
```

Use it something like this:

```
perl 1.pl get /?param=111
```